# How to retrieve value created inside transaction and return it outside transaction in Laravel?

Tags: php, transactions, laravel-5

I am developing a Laravel project. I am using Laravel 5.2. I am working with database and I am manipulating multiple queries at a time. So I am using Laravel built in database transaction function. But my problem is I cannot retrieve value something like last inserted id inside database and return it.

This is how I using transaction

```
$item_code = "";
$id = "";
DB::transaction(function() use ($item_code,$name,$id){
       $item_code = $this->generateItemCode();
       $item = new Item;
       $item->name = $name;
       $item->save();
       $id = $item->id;
})

echo $item_code;
echo $id;
```

In my code, when I print out $item_code and $id. Both are empty. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of options. You can either pass `$item_code` and `$id` by reference into the closure (note the ampersand &)

```
DB::transaction(function() use (&$item_code, $name, &$id){
    $item_code = $this->generateItemCode();
    $item = new Item;
    $item->name = $name;
    $item->save();
    $id = $item->id;
});
```

Or you can return `$item` from the transaction:

```
$item = DB::transaction(function() use ($item_code,$name,$id){
    $item = new Item;
    $item->name = $name;
    $item->save();

    return $item;
});
```